# ListBox and DisplayMember problem in MessageBox

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#. I have problem with take DisplayMember from ListBox.
I try to write simple application in access control. RacsSystem. is the API to access control server.

```
 private void libStrefy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var attendanceZone = libStrefy.SelectedItem as AttendanceZoneData;
        if (attendanceZone != null)
        {
            CalculateAndShowZoneOccupancy(attendanceZone.ID);
            //-----------------------
            var  occupancies = RacsSystem.Instance.Integration.GetAttendanceZoneOccupancies(attendanceZone.ID,
               RacsSystem.Instance.SessionToken);
            //libOsoby.ValueMember = "ID";
           libOsoby.DisplayMember = "Name"; // bez tego nazwa obiektu
           libOsoby.DataSource = occupancies;
           libOsoby.SelectedIndex = 0;

           System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in occupancies)
            {
                sb.Append(item.Name);
                sb.Append(" ---- ");
                sb.Append(item.Description);
                sb.Append(" ++ ");       
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());


        }

    }
```

It's OK show DisplayMember "Name" in MessageBox.

[image]

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

         libOsoby.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;

                 for (int val = 0; val < libOsoby.Items.Count; val++)
                 {
                     libOsoby.SetSelected(val, true);
                 }


                 string strText = "";
                      foreach (var x in libOsoby.SelectedItems)
                          {
                              strText = strText + x.ToString() + "\n";
                          }

                         myReader = new System.IO.StringReader(strText);


                 MessageBox.Show(strText.ToString());

    }
```

It's not ok show me type of data ? I don't know.

[image]

I would like the same effect as in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `strText = strText + x.ToString() + "\n";` with following.

```
strText = strText + x.Text.ToString() + "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but not working :)                 CS1061  C# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  I try change 'var' in foreach statement to 'object' ,but the same error.